# in vscode how to provide compilation command with specific file names

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am trying to debug the following code in vscode. I have 2 versions of the file in the same directory, with minor differences (temp edits during debugging). So I now have 3 files in the directory: go.mod, bug1.go, and bug2.go.

```
//bug1.go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Animal int64

const (
    Goat Animal = iota
    Cat
)

func (n Animal) String() string {
    switch n {
    case Goat:
        return "Goat"
    case Cat:
        return "Cat"
    }
    return "?"
}

type Group struct {
    A, B Animal
}

func main() {

    fmt.Println("Animal: ", Cat)
}
```

I can run the above code from command line like this (which only compiles bug1.go and ignores bug2.go):

```
go run bug1.go
```

Now I am trying to debug bug1.go, using the following launch.json:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch",
      "type": "go",
      "request": "launch",
      "mode": "auto",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "env": {},
      "args": []
    }
  ]
}
```

So I opened bug1.go in vscode, and pressed Run and Debug, and then I am seeing errors being reported from bug2.go. Looks like vscode is trying to compile all the files in the directory together, and is detecting code duplications:

```
Build Error: go build -o /Users/.../bug/__debug_bin -gcflags all=-N -l .
./bug2.go:9:6: Animal redeclared in this block
    ./bug1.go:9:6: other declaration of Animal
./bug2.go:12:5: Goat redeclared in this block
    ./bug1.go:12:5: other declaration of Goat
```

How do I configure vscode to compile only bug1.go and ignore bug2.go?

Comment: on a related topic, if the directory contains multiple similar go files, I also see error marks (underlined in red) in vscode screen, saying something like struct.field not found, even though the file opened in explorer is correct and has all the data definitions and the code works correctly. Deleting the other file versions from the directory removes the false red marks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `program` to `${file}`:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch current file",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "${file}"
        }
    ]
}
```

- `program`: Path to the program folder (or any go file within that folder) when in `debug` or `test` mode, and to the pre-built binary file to debug in `exec` mode. If it is not an absolute path, the extension interpretes it as a workspace relative path.

  (Default: `"${workspaceFolder}"`)

  See [Launch.json attributes](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/debugging.md#launchjson-attributes)
- `${file}`: the current opened file

  see [Variables Reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference)